# ls not displaying files anymore after rm a random file

Tags: linux

so i was using command prompt to make some code in C. Basically in the code I write an array to a file at the end of the code using `fwrite()` and the file is called `output`. Basically I wanted to remove "output" to see what would happened. So I did `$ rm output`. But now when I press `$ ls` nothing appears. If I go to another directory and use `$ ls` it is fine and `$ ls` actually shows all the files. However, `$ ls` does not work in the directory where I used `$ rm output` in. However, if I do `$ vim FILE` where `FILE` is a file I know is in the current directory, it actually shows me the contents. So I know it's still there and not deleted but it's not visible. So I tried to use WinSCP to try to move the folders. But then I got an error message that says

```
Can't get attributes of files 'DIR..'

Command 'ls -la -d  "DIR.." ; echo "WinSCP: this is end-of-file:$status"' failed with invalid output ''.
```

where `DIR` is the path to my directory.

Does anyone know a fix to this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you try this:- move outside this directory and try ls-l path/to/your/directory and show its output

Comment: @JatinMehrota I did and yep it displays all the files. However, I still can't see them with ls

Comment: you did move outside the directort and it displays all the files in the previous directory right?, so now try `mv path/to/directory/* to/your/desired/place`

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I did that and now that folder ls cannot work, also I cant access it with WINSCP

Comment: never mind it is resolved i just realized for some reason I created a file named ls

Comment: @MichaelVLe looks like you answered your own question, that's great! Would you mind adding it as an answer (not just a comment) and marking it as accepted? This will help others that may encounter the same problem in the future. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. I mistakenly created a file called ls